# Can I add a file to one of my GitHub repositories without cloning / pulling from it?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Suppose you have a remote repository on GitHub and you want to add a file to that repository... Can that be done at the Git command line, without pulling all the files from that repository?

Comment: It is not command-line, but you can do this by github.com's user interface, in case you don't know.

Comment: why do you want to do that? your requirement logically doesn't make sense. if you don't have the repo locally, how can you add files and push it to the remote?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr One use case: imagine you just deleted a clone of one of your very large projects from your machine, but realised you forgot to add a file. Instead of cloning the whole project from GitHub only to add that file, you can simply use the GitHub interface. However, I personally prefer to do everything locally: less risk of screwing up.

Comment: @Jubobs i understand that but it still doesn't make sense. op's talking about doing it in cli.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Ah! You're right. What the OP wants is not possible with Git itself, but, since [GitHub allows it through its web interface](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-new-files/), it should also be possible at the command line with the GitHub API.

Comment: I want to do it because sometimes I'm lazy and don't want to copy everything whenever I work on another computer. Disappointed that this isn't possible with CLI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Suppose you have a remote repository on GitHub and you want to add a file to that repository... Can that be done at the Git command line, without pulling all the files from that repository?

The GitHub API now allows you to create, update, or delete a *text* file in one of your GitHub repositories **at the command line**, which creates a commit in the process; see [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file).

Alternatively, if you're not bent on using the command line, you can add a *text* file to one of your GitHub remote repo **through the GitHub web interface**; see [this](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-new-files/).

---

However, adding a file (text or otherwise) to a remote repository is *not* possible with Git itself. You have no other choice but to

1. clone the remote repo (or pull from it, if you already have a clone),
2. add the file and create a commit in your local repo,
3. push that commit to the remote.

(Of course, that's under the assumption that you have read and write access to that remote.)